# Meteor UglifyJS error when trying to compile in production

Tags: javascript, meteor, galaxy, uglifyjs

Trying to upload to Galaxy causes the error so I am debugging with the following:

`meteor --settings settings-dev.json --production`

```
While minifying app code:
  eval at <anonymous>
  (/Users/sergiy/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1),
  <anonymous>:1545:18: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ())
  at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous>
  (/Users/sergiy/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1),
  <anonymous>:1545:18)
  at js_error (eval at <anonymous>
  (/Users/sergiy/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1),
  <anonymous>:1553:11)
  at croak (eval at <anonymous>
  (/Users/sergiy/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1),
  <anonymous>:2089:9)
  at token_error (eval at <anonymous>
  (/Users/sergiy/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1),
  <anonymous>:2097:9)
  at unexpected (eval at <anonymous>
  (/Users/sergiy/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1),
  <anonymous>:2103:9)
  at expr_atom (eval at <anonymous>
  (/Users/sergiy/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1),
  <anonymous>:2618:13)
  at maybe_unary (eval at <anonymous>
  (/Users/sergiy/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1),
  <anonymous>:2792:19)
  at expr_ops (eval at <anonymous>
  (/Users/sergiy/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1),
  <anonymous>:2827:24)
  at maybe_conditional (eval at <anonymous>
  (/Users/sergiy/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1),
  <anonymous>:2832:20)


  * Many more lines of same kind of stuff*


=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Which really gives me no starting point as to what's causing the problem. There is a [running issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5387) on GitHub but no progress so far.

I tried to dig deeper and did the following in my Terminal

```
alias uglifyjs=~/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs
find lib client -type f -name \*.js|while read file;do uglifyjs -o /dev/null $file;done
```

Which comes back with

```
  Parse error at client/main.js:1,7
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token: string (/imports/startup/client)
  Error
   at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/sergiy/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1545:18)
   at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/sergiy/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1553:11)
   at croak (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/sergiy/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2089:9)
   at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/sergiy/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2097:9)
   at unexpected (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/sergiy/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2103:9)
   at semicolon (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/sergiy/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2123:56)
   at simple_statement (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/sergiy/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2314:73)
   at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/sergiy/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2183:19)
   at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/sergiy/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2136:24)
   at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/sergiy/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.1ldi2wj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2904:23)
```

My `main.js` file looks like this:

`import '/imports/startup/client';`

Still can't figure out what the issue is since that is the syntax Meteor suggests in their docs. Removing the `standard-minifier-js` packages fixes the problem but that's not the best way to go around it so I was hoping there was a fix!

Comment: Have you included either the ecmascript or babel packages in your project?

Comment: Does your app run without `--production`?

Comment: @Khang, yes it does since the `standard-minifiers-js` package only kicks in during production bundles ie deploying to Galaxy or running it with `--production`

Comment: @Mikkel I have the `ecmascript` package in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an issue with an NPM package ([ClipboardJS](https://clipboardjs.com/)) I was importing in one of my components. Removing it and adding the script to my `<head></head>` fixed the issue. I'd rather have a minified app with an external `src` than a non-minified app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no harmony support on UglifyJS stable yet as of 2.7.5.

On https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2 there is a harmony and a harmony-v2.7.5 branch though. Support for modules there isn't fully implemented yet as of today and harmony support is still experimental although many features have been implemented already.

Comment: how would I implement it application-wide to mimic `standard-minifiers-js`?

Comment: There is still some work to do before uglifyJS harmony can be release as stable. Even though those depending on uglifyJS might want to use the harmony branch I don't think it's worth it, even if that branch might be at least as stable for es5.1 features (measured by the tests we have, though there might be instability).

And there is also no easy way to implement it, except by changing the package.json by making it refer to a harmony github branch or commit url.